# EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1 result set

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to run a simple R code in SQL  Server 2016:

```
    EXEC sp_execute_external_script
   @language =N'R',
    @script=N'OutputDataSet<-InputDataSet',
    @input_data_1 =N'SELECT 1 AS hello'
    WITH RESULT SETS (([hello] int not null));
   GO
```

I have followed this link to configure: https://tomaztsql.wordpress.com/2016/07/26/enabling-sp_execute_external_script-to-run-r-scripts-in-sql-server-2016/

I'm getting error:

```
    Msg 39023, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_execute_external_script, 
     Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
     'sp_execute_external_script' is disabled on this instance of SQL 
  Server. Use sp_configure 'external scripts enabled' to enable it.
  Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
 EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1 
  result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run time.

     when I checked with :

  EXECUTE sp_configure;
  GO
  The result shows like this:
  name                    minimum         maximum        config_value      run_value
  external scripts enabled  0          1                1                0
```

Why the run value is still 0 (note-I have SQL Server Launchpad restarted)? What is the resolution for this?

Comment: Did you run the actual `sp_configure` and `reconfigure` commands, and then *restart SQL Server*, like the post goes on to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. need to restart SQL Server services. Which will restart everything. And its working fine.